# How to read and parse data from PubSub topic into a beam pipeline and print it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a program which creates a topic in pubSub and also publishes messages to the topic. I also have an automated dataflow job(using a template) which saves these messages into my BigQuery table. Now I intend to replace the template based job with a python pipeline where my requirement is to read data from PubSub, apply transformations and save the data into BigQuery/publish to another PubSub topic. I started writing the script in python and did a lot of trial and error to achieve it but to my dismay, I could not achieve it. The code looks like this:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
TOPIC_PATH = "projects/test-pipeline-253103/topics/test-pipeline-topic"
OUTPUT_PATH = "projects/test-pipeline-253103/topics/topic-repub"

def run():
    o = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=o)

    print("I reached here")
    # # Read from PubSub into a PCollection.
    data = (
        p
        | "Read From Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC_PATH)
    )
    data | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=OUTPUT_PATH)
    print("Lines: ", data)
run()
```

I will really appreciate if I can get some help at the earliest.
Note: I have my project set up on google cloud and I have my script running locally.

Answer (score 5):

Here the working code.

```
import apache_beam as beam

TOPIC_PATH = "projects/test-pipeline-253103/topics/test-pipeline-topic"
OUTPUT_PATH = "projects/test-pipeline-253103/topics/topic-repub"


class PrintValue(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print(element)
        return [element]

def run():

    o = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()
    # Replace this by --stream execution param
    standard_options = o.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.StandardOptions)
    standard_options.streaming = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=o)

    print("I reached here")
    # # Read from PubSub into a PCollection.
    data = p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC_PATH) | beam.ParDo(PrintValue()) | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=OUTPUT_PATH)
    # Don't forget to run the pipeline!
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

run()
```

In summary

- You miss to run the pipeline. Indeed, Beam is a Graph programming model. So, in your previous code, you built your graph but you never run it. Here, at the end, run it (not blocking call) and wait the end (blocking call)
- When you start your pipeline, Beam mention that PubSub work only in streaming mode. Thus, you can start your code with `--streaming` param, or do it programmatically as shown in my code

Be careful, streaming mode means to listen indefinitively on PubSub. If you run this on Dataflow, your pipeline will be always up, until you stop it. This can be cost expensive if you have few message. Be sure that is the target model

An alternative is to use your pipeline for a limited period of time (you use scheduler for starting it, and another one for stopping it). But, at this moment, you have to stack message. Here you use a `Topic` as entry of the pipeline. This option force Beam to create a temporary subscription and to listen message on this subscription. This means that the message publish before this subscription creation won't be received and processed.

The idea is to create a subscription, by this way the message will be stacked in it (up to 7 days, by default). Then, use the subscription name in entry of your pipeline `beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUB_PATH)`. The messages will be unstacked and processed by Beam (Order not guaranteed!)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Beam programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms), you simply have to add a Transform step in your pipeline. Here an example or transform:

```
class PrintValue(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    print(element)
    return [element]
```

Add it to your pipeline

```
 data |  beam.ParDo(PrintValue()) | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=OUTPUT_PATH)
```

You can add the number of transforms that you want. You can test the value and set the elements in tagged PCollection (for having multiple output) for fan out, or use side input for fan in PCollection.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but again i am not able to send any data 
to the output pubsub topic nor is it printing any element. I am not 
sure what im doing wrong. WHat i did is this 
`data = ( p | "Read From Pub/Sub"` `>>beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC_PATH) `
 `| beam.ParDo(PrintValue()) | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=OUTPUT_PATH) ) `
Also, I have my printValue class in the same file. please suggest whats wrong?

Comment: Ok, you are something wrong. My short response is good; I publish a more complete one (and longer!)

Answer (score 0):

```html
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Set the Google Cloud project ID
project_id = 'your-project-id'

# Set the Pub/Sub topic and subscription names
topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}'
subscription_name = 'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_name}'

# Define the pipeline options
options = PipelineOptions(
    streaming=True,
    runner='DirectRunner',  # Use DirectRunner for testing, DataflowRunner for production
    project=project_id,
    region='us-central1',
)

# Create a Pub/Sub message publisher transform
class PubsubMessagePublisher(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, topic_name):
        self.topic_name = topic_name

    def process(self, element):
        # Publish the message to the Pub/Sub topic
        from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        publisher.publish(self.topic_name, element.encode('utf-8'))

# Create a Pub/Sub message subscriber transform
class PubsubMessageSubscriber(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, subscription_name):
        self.subscription_name = subscription_name

    def start_bundle(self):
        # Create a Pub/Sub subscriber client and subscribe to the topic
        from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
        self.subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
        self.subscriber.subscribe(self.subscription_name, callback=self.process_message)

    def process_message(self, message):
        # Process the received message
        print(f"Received message: {message.data.decode('utf-8')}")
        message.ack()

    def finish_bundle(self):
        # Stop the Pub/Sub subscriber client
        self.subscriber.stop()

# Define the pipeline
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
    # Send messages to Pub/Sub topic
    messages = ['Message 1', 'Message 2', 'Message 3']
    (
        pipeline
        | "Create Messages" >> beam.Create(messages)
        | "Publish Messages" >> beam.ParDo(PubsubMessagePublisher(topic_name))
    )

    # Receive messages from Pub/Sub subscription
    (
        pipeline
        | "Subscribe to Pubsub Subscription" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_name)
        | "Process Messages" >> beam.ParDo(PubsubMessageSubscriber(subscription_name))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
#sending data to pubsub topic
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Set your Google Cloud project ID, Pub/Sub topic, and BigQuery table details
project_id = 'your-project-id'
pubsub_topic = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_name}'
bq_table = 'your-project-id.your_dataset.your_table'

# Define the Apache Beam pipeline options
options = PipelineOptions()
options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions).project = project_id
options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions).region = 'us-central1'
options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions).job_name = 'bigquery-to-pubsub'
options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location = 'gs://your-bucket/staging'
options.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location = 'gs://your-bucket/temp'

# Define the pipeline
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

# Step 1: Read data from BigQuery
query = f'SELECT * FROM {bq_table}'
read_from_bq = pipeline | 'Read from BigQuery' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True))

# Step 2: Send data to Pub/Sub
def format_message(row):
    return row  # Modify this function to format the row as per your requirements

send_to_pubsub = read_from_bq | 'Format as Pub/Sub messages' >> beam.Map(format_message)
send_to_pubsub | 'Send to Pub/Sub' >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=pubsub_topic)

# Run the pipeline
result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()

#receiving data from pubsub topic
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery


# Define your Pub/Sub topic and subscription
pubsub_topic = 'projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/topics/YOUR_TOPIC'
subscription = 'projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/subscriptions/YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION'

# Define your BigQuery output table details
output_table = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID:YOUR_DATASET.YOUR_TABLE'


def run():
    # Set up pipeline options
    options = PipelineOptions()
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    # Create a Pipeline using the defined options
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    # Read messages from Pub/Sub topic
    messages = pipeline | 'Read Pub/Sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)

    # Transform the messages as needed
    transformed_data = messages | 'Transform Data' >> beam.Map(lambda msg: your_transform_function(msg))

    # Define the BigQuery schema for the output table
    table_schema = {
        'fields': [
            {'name': 'field1', 'type': 'STRING'},
            {'name': 'field2', 'type': 'INTEGER'},
            # Add more fields as needed
        ]
    }

    # Write the transformed data to BigQuery
    transformed_data | 'Write to BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(
        table=output_table,
        schema=table_schema,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    )

    # Run the pipeline
    pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()


def your_transform_function(message):
    # Implement your own transformation logic here
    # This function should transform the incoming Pub/Sub message into a dictionary
    # with field names matching the BigQuery schema fields
    # For example:
    transformed_message = {
        'field1': message['field1'],
        'field2': int(message['field2']),
        # Add more fields as needed
    }
    return transformed_message


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

#read and print pubsub topic data
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Define your pipeline options
options = PipelineOptions()

# Define your pipeline
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

# Define your Pub/Sub topic and subscription
topic = "projects/<your-project>/topics/<your-topic>"
subscription = "projects/<your-project>/subscriptions/<your-subscription>"

# Read data from the Pub/Sub topic
messages = (
    pipeline
    | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic, subscription=subscription)
)

# Process the messages (e.g., print them)
def process_message(message):
    print(message)

processed_messages = (
    messages
    | "Process messages" >> beam.Map(process_message)
)

# Run the pipeline
result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Define your pipeline options
options = PipelineOptions()

# Define your pipeline
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

# Define your BigQuery table
table_spec = "<your-project>:<your-dataset>.<your-table>"

# Read data from the BigQuery table
rows = (
    pipeline
    | "Read from BigQuery" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=table_spec)
)

# Transform the rows into Pub/Sub messages
def transform_to_pubsub(row):
    # Convert the row to a Pub/Sub message
    message = str(row)
    return message

pubsub_messages = (
    rows
    | "Transform to Pub/Sub messages" >> beam.Map(transform_to_pubsub)
)

# Write the messages to a Pub/Sub topic
topic = "projects/<your-project>/topics/<your-topic>"
pubsub_messages | "Write to Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=topic)

# Run the pipeline
result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# Define your pipeline options
options = PipelineOptions()

# Define your pipeline
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

# Define your Pub/Sub topic and subscription
topic = "projects/<your-project>/topics/<your-topic>"
subscription = "projects/<your-project>/subscriptions/<your-subscription>"

# Read data from the Pub/Sub topic
messages = (
    pipeline
    | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic, subscription=subscription)
)

# Process the messages (e.g., print them)
def process_message(message):
    print(message)

processed_messages = (
    messages
    | "Process messages" >> beam.Map(process_message)
)

# Run the pipeline
result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```